# Velocity Template and Java String

Tags: java, highcharts, jira, velocity

I develop jira report plugin.Velocity template shows ascii code single or double quote in java string.

Java Code:

**Main:**

```
    Map velocityParams = new HashMap();
    String horizontalAxis = convertKeysToWeekCategories(bugtrends.keySet());

    velocityParams.put("horizontalAxis", horizontalAxis);
```

**convertKeysToWeekCategories method:**

```
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();

    for (Integer integer : keySet) {
        build.append("\'");
        build.append("W");
        build.append(integer.toString());
        build.append("\'");
        build.append(",");
    }

    String result = build.toString();

    result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);

    return result;

}
```

And I draw with HighChart api.

**bugstrendview.vm:**

```
<head >
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<script>AJS.$(document).ready(function(){ 


    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: true,
            filename: "open-bugs-trend-chart"
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Open Bugs Trend',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'results are displayed in weeks',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [$horizontalAxis],
            labels: {
                rotation: -90,
                align: 'right',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {

        formatter: function() {
            var myDates = $tooltipDates;
            return "<b>W"+(this.point.x+1)+"</b><br/>"+
            myDates[this.point.x]+" - "+myDates[this.point.x + 1]+
            "<br/>"+"Total Bugs : "+this.point.y ;

        },
    },


        yAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            minorGridLineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of Open Bugs'
            },
            min: 0,
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                marker: {
                    enable: true
                }
            }
        },
        series: [
        {
            showInLegend: false,
            data: [$verticalAxis]
        }]
    });        });

</script>
```

Then shows in the bugstrendview.vm categories:[`&#39;`W1`&#39;`] as error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &' and of course dont draw.

Why shows ascii code of single quote?

Comment: Did you copied something from a doc,text file ?

Comment: I did not fully understand your question.This plugin works jira 5 but dont work jira 6.4.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the `'` gets encoded to `&#39;`

See this thread:

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/24351/how-to-prevent-velocity-escape-html

appending `WithHtml` to a variable name should prevent HTML escaping

You can do:

```
#set($horizontalAxisWithHtml = $horizontalAxis)
```

and then use `$horizontalAxisWithHtml`

Comment: Thak you answer.This works!!.Today I learned something about velocity.

Comment: Unfortunately appending `WithHtml` seemed to have no effect for me.